# Convert negative to positive percentage range into 1-10 scale

Tags: scales, percentage, range

I know how to convert a range of positive % numbers into any positive integer scale, but am having trouble figuring out how to do it when my % range includes negative %s.

Example:
I have the following 5 %'s I want to convert to a 1-10 scale:
-10%, -5%, 3%, 5%, 25%

I need to make these become numbers between 1-10. 
How would I go about doing this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Add 11% to all values.  Now apply what you know.

Comment: Great it worked, thank you!